# the interior of a set is in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $1<p< \infty$ and $n\in \mathbb N^*$.

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n,\: 0< \mu (\Omega) < \infty $ and $ P=\{x\in L^p(\Omega): x(t)\geq 0, \:a.e.\:t\in\Omega \} $.

I want to find the interior of $P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interior is empty. If possible let $x$ be an interior point of $P$. Then there exists $r>0$ such that $\|x-y\| <r$ implies $y \in P$. Let $E$ be a set whose measure is, say $s$, and define $y(t)=x(t)$ if $t \notin E$, $y(t)=-1$ if $t \in E$. Then $\int|x-y|^{p}=\int_E |x+1|^{p} <r^{p}$ provided $s$ is small enough. But $y \notin P$ since $y=-1$ on a set of positive measure.

I have used the fact that if $f$ is an integrable function and $\epsilon>0$ then there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\int_E |f|  d\mu <\epsilon$ whenever $\mu(E) <\delta$.